# Where can I find this S. Mrówka's paper?

Tags: gn.general-topology, paper-request

I have been looking for a digital version of the following article: "S. Mrowka, *On universal spaces*, Bull Acad. Polon. Sci., cl. III, **4** (1956) 479-481". There is a MathSciNet review made by J. Isbell here: [On universal spaces](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=89401), but that's pretty much all I could find online. If any of you know where to get this paper, I'd really appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: the journal has not been digitized, but many libraries have it: https://www.worldcat.org/title/bulletin-de-lacademie-polonaise-des-sciences-serie-des-sciences-mathematiques-astronomiques-et-physiques/oclc/1585821

Comment: Or see Problems 2.7.7.and 2.7.8 in Engelking's *General Topology*

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. In Isbell's review it says: "It is shown that for every cardinal $m$ there is a $T_1$-space which admits no non-constant
continuous mapping into a $T_1$-space of power less than $m$". I was hoping to read exactly what Mrówka had done, but from Carlo's comment I guess that's going to be very difficult.

Comment: that journal is notoriously difficult to obtain papers from. you will likely have to submit a request through your university library.

Comment: My guess: take a set $X$ of cardinality larger than $m$ with the co-finite topology. Then if $Y$ is $T_1$ of cardinality less than $m$  and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous then there is a $y$ such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is infinite; as it is also closed it must be all of $X$.

Comment: I think that with the reference to Engelking's exercises combined with the comments about the difficulties one has in accessing the journal, I will desist from consulting the original article. Thank you all so much for your help.